# Why isn't my variable getting defined, and ending this loop?

Tags: ruby

I ran across this issue.  I have a work around, so I'm specifically asking WHY this doesn't work?  Why doesn't the variable get defined in the first time through the loop, and then exit the loop?

Assuming it's the scope, which I'm convinced it is, then why is foo defined after breaking the loop?  Am I just seeing an artifact of irb here?

```
voin0017:[/home/acowell/src/local/goldrhel] ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
voin0017:[/home/acowell/src/local/goldrhel] irb
irb(main):001:0> while defined?(foo).nil? ; foo = 1 ;  end
^CIRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
        from (irb):1:in `call'
        from (irb):1
        from /opt/chef/embedded/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> p foo
1
=> 1
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: On Ruby version 2.1.2, the while loop just hangs, which doesn't make sense either. Edit: That's what happened for you, missed the Ctrl-C. Edit 2: If `foo` is defined before the loop, it doesn't hang and just exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not a variable is defined depends upon not only the scope, but also on its location within the ruby script. That is, a variable is defined only if it has been defined previously within the *parse*, not the *execution*.

Here's an example:

```
begin
    puts "Is foo defined? #{defined?(foo).inspect}" # foo is never defined here
    foo ||= 1
    puts "but now foo is #{foo}" # foo is always defined here
    foo += 1
end while foo <= 3
```

Output:

```
Is foo defined? nil
but now foo is 1
Is foo defined? nil
but now foo is 2
Is foo defined? nil
but now foo is 3
```

Because `foo` has not been defined previously within the script on the first line of the loop, it is undefined at that point, and remains undefined, even if it is assigned to and the same line is returned to at a later point during execution.

This is why `foo` in the `while` condition of the question is always undefined:

```
while defined?(foo).nil? # foo is always undefined
    foo = 1
end
```

and will loop forever. In contrast, this loop only executes once:

```
begin
    foo = 1
end while defined?(foo).nil? # foo is defined
```

because `foo` is assigned to previously in the parse.

---

**Edit:**

Only loops that require a block seem to isolate its local variables from living outside of it. E.g. `loop`, `upto`, `each`, `inject`, `map`, `times`, etc. These all require use of the keyword `do` and `end`, or curly braces, which delimit the block. In contrast, `while`, `until`, and `for` do not, and so variables defined within them continue to live outside of them. This is demonstrated here:

```
while true
    foo_while = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_while: #{defined?(foo_while).inspect}"

until false
    foo_until = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_until: #{defined?(foo_until).inspect}"

for i in 0..2
    foo_for = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_for: #{defined?(foo_for).inspect}"

loop do
    foo_loop = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_loop: #{defined?(foo_loop).inspect}"

1.upto(2) do |i|
    foo_upto = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_upto: #{defined?(foo_upto).inspect}"

[1,2,3].each do |i|
    foo_each = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_each: #{defined?(foo_each).inspect}"

[1,2,3].inject do |i,j|
    foo_inject = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_inject: #{defined?(foo_inject).inspect}"

[1,2,3].map do |i|
    foo_map = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_map: #{defined?(foo_map).inspect}"

3.times do
    foo_times = 1
    break
end
puts "foo_times: #{defined?(foo_times).inspect}"
```

Output:

```
foo_while: "local-variable"
foo_until: "local-variable"
foo_for: "local-variable"
foo_loop: nil
foo_upto: nil
foo_each: nil
foo_inject: nil
foo_map: nil
foo_times: nil
```

Comment: This is indeed strange behavior, but your answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

The `defined?` method does not test if a *value* is defined for a variable, but instead if that variable is defined within the scope you're testing it in.

The code you've written here is basically nonsensical:

```
while (defined?(foo).nil?)
  foo = 1
end
```

The `foo` variable is never "defined" outside of the context of the `while` block so it spins forever waiting for that to happen. You end up defining it repeatedly inside the context of the `while` loop, but that `defined?` check does not test that. It is getting defined, just not where you expected it to be.

If you add a little code to see what's going on you get this:

```
puts defined?(foo).inspect
# => nil

while (true)
  foo = 1

  puts defined?(foo).inspect
  # => "local-variable"

  break
end

# Once the while completes, the variable is defined outside that scope.
puts defined?(foo).inspect
# => "local-variable"
```

The general pattern you're going in idiomatic Ruby code looks more like this

```
foo = nil

while (!foo)
  foo = 1
end
```

As a note, it's highly unusual to see `defined?` used in Ruby applications as variables are either used, or not used. It's in situations where you have some automatic code generation and block rebinding going on that you want to test local variables before using them. The most common case for this rare behaviour is within Rails partials where you *may* have passed in options via the `:local` argument. These appear as local variables if defined, but may not exist, so you need to test to be sure.

Comment: `foo` _is_ defined after the loop (the last `puts` shows `local-variable` not `nil`), at least on my current Ruby (2.1.2).

Comment: Same here. I am using 1.9.3p484. `while defined?(foo).nil? ; foo = 1 ; break ; end ; while defined?(foo).nil? ; foo = 2 ; break ; end ; p foo` outputs `1`, meaning that after the first loop `foo == 1` and so the second loop is skipped.

Comment: I agree the example is weird, but I stumbled across it trying to look at the logic of testing against a 3rd party object, which (apparently) may or may not have properties based or other logic.  Any idea on why foo is defined outside of the loop, though?